# Different output for the same input data

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application

Why does this code return 10 on the test machine for the input data:

```
5
4 2 3 3 3
```

while on my PC it correctly returns 12?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int n;
int b[99];
int money = 0;

int min()
{
    int min = b[0];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (b[i] < min && b[i] % 2 != 0) {
            min = b[i];
            index = i;
        }
    for (int i = index; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        b[i] = b[i + 1];
    }
    b[n - 1] = 0;
    return min;
}

int main()
{
    money = 0;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> b[i];
        money += b[i];
    }
    while (money % 2 != 0)
    {
        money -= min();
    }
    if (money % 2 == 0)
        if (money != 0)
            cout << money;
        else cout << "NIESTETY";


        system("pause");
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: It happened on my PC too, once. But for other input data it works perfectly. And i'm not talking about some simple values. I've run some recommended tests for this problem, this for example:

```
581
906 369 899 998 73 717 269 51 875 61 123 237 50 924 576 52 693 394 952 24 534 452 634 139 642 570 20 643 128 165 144 867 86 256 981 26 344 912 489 524 667 375 502 944 961 61 586 834 62 240 644 602 563 758 587 973 440 920 977 785 999 186 384 231 414 184 84 492 277 787 737 312 849 595 238 892 377 103 275 797 847 652 263 526 473 643 972 701 209 70 95 852 337 387 651 451 843 649 445 172 592 299 110 479 191 148 324 600 928 258 354 693 522 637 977 180 394 306 846 885 85 339 678 355 799 297 232 929 133 173 698 362 592 426 319 690 195 944 143 571 831 765 847 106 293 460 650 4 876 891 272 987 171 767 495 486 161 243 959 431 707 761 634 574 774 176 84 903 102 223 7 759 886 113 626 917 873 177 307 46 56 415 162 537 845 956 704 725 551 266 673 255 567 520 278 1000 450 573 205 447 656 946 460 331 317 125 340 372 246 635 667 642 422 766 669 894 217 759 396 160 985 46 61 832 375 272 276 49 820 440 259 482 569 97 903 135 164 570 412 320 827 403 610 577 350 543 328 481 136 595 584 935 830 134 587 658 604 865 742 111 668 313 669 233 592 451 735 539 890 319 882 674 306 376 945 313 872 683 915 92 954 598 750 106 576 259 563 293 158 708 716 259 434 833 867 754 678 576 981 55 8 421 31 176 641 707 175 531 299 65 55 118 990 696 533 713 829 20 310 201 748 697 397 550 909 584 366 6 515 298 128 483 454 564 986 171 225 35 733 664 368 674 146 479 70 610 734 708 550 962 227 606 520 751 449 254 6 253 757 942 63 926 592 768 516 843 187 836 722 329 745 54 703 437 671 463 288 548 847 563 354 964 27 100 120 351 928 557 757 937 872 417 18 335 181 68 834 994 83 178 67 45 965 31 976 155 883 726 173 813 66 199 211 619 429 643 237 464 586 929 546 675 392 350 811 187 936 64 167 394 969 36 630 430 377 905 283 36 352 221 293 125 975 214 903 622 769 955 759 83 104 988 876 612 308 495 612 634 288 581 164 595 685 620 817 988 355 134 71 159 493 730 952 70 620 961 407 78 159 660 542 991 858 101 140 531 156 667 323 621 365 193 825 252 848 897 5 16 277 461 909 549 194 638 422 718 979 705 515 499 488 447 249 229 382 315 851 625 249 818 889 580 224 926 270 734 689 275 842 834 838 774 949 101 728 930 478 397 188 228 675 36 259 834 745 629 374 664 335 30 745 963 918 38 848 482 739 745 912 154 408 250 271 480 767 120 142 652 169 764 541 228 919 482 984 942 631 46 529 395 576

//Output: 289826
```

Comment: Start by explaining what your program actually does.

Comment: Do you have the use of the test machine? If not, then this behavior is irreproducible.

Comment: I don't. But still, there must be something that can cause this, since it happened once on my own PC as well.
Edit: But when I run the program again, with a few breakpoints, it worked just fine.

Comment: Aren't there some mistakes frequently made in C++ that could lead to such an outcome? I'm not really used to C++, since normally I code in C#. C++ is mostly for schoolwork

Comment: @Reynevan Yes there are plenty... but your code looks ok. Can you find a way to repro the issue and provide more details? Otherwise it's quite hard to see the root cause.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to.
I tried to reproduce it, but it doesn't happen often on my main PC, and it never happened on my laptop, which I have access to right now.
Other thing I noticed: When I send the code to them for the test run (not as an answer for a problem) it works just fine every single time. Output is crearly 12

Comment: I reproduced the error.
It returns 10 when input = 5 2 4 3 3 3, but works when input = 5 4 2 3 3 3